# Insert object into MongoDB array element

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I have to insert an object in every array in the MongoDB document. The `items` array displayed below has `itemList`; in every `itemList` I have to insert a `itemSpec`. The desired document shape before and after the process is shown below:

Before process

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "itemList":{
        "rejected": true
      },
      "fProcBy": "automatic"
    },
    {
      "itemList":{
        "rejected": true
      },
      "fProcBy": "automatic"
    }
  ]
}
```

After process:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "itemList":{
        "rejected": true
      },
      "itemSpec":{
        "approved": true
      },
      "fProcBy": "automatic"
    },
    {
      "itemList":{
        "rejected": true
      },
      "itemSpec":{
        "approved": true
      },
      "fProcBy": "automatic"
    }
  ]
}
```

So in each element of the `items` array there has to be inserted a new object property `itemSpec`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a solution which does it in a single run, but with the following simple script the maximal number of iterations is equal to the maximal number of array elements you have in a single documents, which is probably not so high (but it's just a guess as I have no further information about your data):

```
var q = { "items.itemSpec": null };
var u = { 
    $set: {
        "items.$.itemSpec" : {
            "approved": true
        }
    }
};
var yourColl = db.getCollection('fooBar');
while (yourColl.find(q).count() > 0) {
    yourColl.update(q, u, { multi: true });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **$push** operator to update array in a document.

**Try This:**

```
db.test.update({"_id":"yourUniqueId"}, 
              {$push: {  "items":{ "itemSpec":{"approved": true}}}});
```

Comment: this will add the itemSpec as "an element" of the items array. OP wants to add it inside the actual elements instead

Comment: It creating new array element as below, I have to update as I mentioned above {
  "items": [
    {
      "itemList": {
        "rejected": true
      },
      "fProcBy": "automatic"
    },
    {
      "itemList": {
        "rejected": true
      },
      "fProcBy": "automatic"
    },
    {
      "itemSpec": {
        "approved": true
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I did not get what you wanted to say!!!   can you tell me what is the issue

Comment: did you try "items.0"?

Comment: I have n number of items in the array i have to insert "itemSpec":{
        "approved": true,
      } in the each and every array element without specifying particular object example item[0]

Comment: ya that i know i am just asking if item.0 worked or not bcoz i cannot test right nw.

Comment: code u provided is adding new array item[2], in the given example, the code has to insert the itemSpec, in available array elements as mentioned in the after process